# R dplyr/tidyr: "mutate" new columns with data from other observations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to create two new variables using dplyr/tidyr functions by using data from previous but related rows.  In my example, I have a data.frame with the data for ID, YEAR and AMOUNT (see below).

```
    ID   YEAR    AMOUNT
    A    2000    4
    B    2000    4
    A    2001    2
    B    2001    3
    A    2002    3
    B    2002    1
```

I want to create the last two columns dynamically (see below) using dplyr/tidyr (I found a way to do it regularly but I'd be interested to know how to do it in the latest version in dplyr/tidyr).

```
    ID   YEAR    AMOUNT    YtY_VARIANCE    Y_VARIANCE
    A    2000    4         0               0
    B    2000    4         0               0
    A    2001    2         -2              -2
    B    2001    3         -1              -1
    A    2002    3         +1              -1
    B    2002    1         -2              -3
```

Where YtY_VARIANCE is obtained by subtracting the amount from the previous year and Y_VARIANCE is obtained by subtracting the amount from the first year (always).

I would expect code like this:

```
    raw_data %>%
        group_by(ID, YEAR) # Not even sure if that's required?!?
        mutate(YtY_VARIANCE = xxx(), Y_VARIANCE = yyy() )
```

What should be xxx and yyy?!  Is that even possible?

Anyone can tell or point me to an answer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
 raw_data %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      mutate(YtY_VARIANCE=AMOUNT-lag(AMOUNT),
       YtY_VARIANCE=replace(YtY_VARIANCE, which(is.na(YtY_VARIANCE)), 0), 
      Y_VARIANCE=AMOUNT-AMOUNT[1L])
 #      ID YEAR AMOUNT YtY_VARIANCE Y_VARIANCE
 #1  A 2000      4            0          0
 #2  B 2000      4            0          0
 #3  A 2001      2           -2         -2
 #4  B 2001      3           -1         -1
 #5  A 2002      3            1         -1
 #6  B 2002      1           -2         -3
```

Comment: plus one. You could also do `YtY_VARIANCE=pmax(AMOUNT-lag(AMOUNT), 0, na.rm=TRUE)` and `Y_VARIANCE=AMOUNT-first(AMOUNT)`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde  Thanks, I tried the `pmax` line, but it gives `[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0`  
I am using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Matthew and Akrun!  With both your solutions, I was able to find the final solution.

Akrun's suggested solution worked within my simple model but it was still having issues within my bigger/complex/final model.  The final solution I ended up with was to combine both:

```
    raw_data %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      arrange(YEAR) %>%
      mutate(YtY_VARIANCE=AMOUNT-lag(AMOUNT),
             YtY_VARIANCE=replace(YtY_VARIANCE, which(is.na(YtY_VARIANCE)), 0), 
             Y_VARIANCE=AMOUNT-first(AMOUNT))
```

Thanks for your help!  And hopefully, it will help others!